# How to pass a varible through a php file to bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

I need to run a bash script from php file. Here is my try...

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/home/svradmin/scripts');
$output = shell_exec('./testbash.sh');
chdir($old_path);
```

My `testbash.sh` as follows..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

This works fine... Now I need to pass an variable from my php function and according to that the bash script should run.. lets say as an example..

```
   function fcn1() {
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/svradmin/scripts');
    $output = shell_exec('./testbash.sh');//need to pass variable 'fcn1'
    chdir($old_path);
    }



   function fcn2() {
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/svradmin/scripts');
    $output = shell_exec('./testbash.sh');//need to pass variable 'fcn2'
    chdir($old_path);
    }
```

So the bash script need to change as below,

```
     #!/bin/bash
//If variable fcn1 received
    echo "Hello World!! fcn1 has executed.."

//If variable fcn2 received
    echo "Hello World!! fcn2 has executed.."
```

Comment: _"need to pass variable 'fcn1'"_? What do you mean? Passing the string `fcn1` or the content of the PHP variable `fcn1`?

Comment: Content of the variable fcn1

Comment: You need to design this from the viewpoint of the shell script. How do you want that script to receive the variable? As a parameter, or via the environment, or via stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXAMPLE**

Just put  your variable(s) after the call --

```
$output = shell_exec('./testbash.sh your_var_1 your_var_2');
```

Then in your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$1
var2=$2

echo "Hello World, var 1 is $var1 and var 2 is $var2"
```

**UPDATE**

So your function would look like:

```
function fcn2() {
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/svradmin/scripts');
    $var = "Hello Hello";
    // Or as Fravadona suggested:
    $var = escapeshellarg("Hello Hello");
    $output = shell_exec("./testbash.sh $var");
    chdir($old_path);
    return $output;
}

function fcn1() {
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/svradmin/scripts');
    $var = "Hello";
    // Or as Fravadona suggested:
    $var = escapeshellarg("Hello");
    $output = shell_exec("./testbash.sh $var");
    chdir($old_path);
    return $output;
}

echo fcn1();
echo fcn2();
```

And your bash ..

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$1

echo "Hello World!! $var has executed.."
```

Comment: Thanks!! what if I need to include it in if function? like if var1 received only run that

Comment: See my update :)

Comment: No,, I dont need so many bash scripts. I need only one script.. From that particular script, I need if functions to get the content of fcn variable..

Comment: That 3 liner will do exactly that .. It's a SINGLE bash script ..  My first statement is merely an example ..  Showing you CAN have two variables if you so choose to ..

Comment: if fcn1(as an variable content) has received(from php to bash script) I need to run/echo "Hello " and if fcn2 has received i need to run/echo "Hello Hello". How do to this?

Comment: See final update .. It seems you need a refresher in the basic understanding of variables and where/when/how to use  them.  My first example should have been more than enough to get you on your way.

Comment: As @Fravadona mentioned .. Since we don't know what you'll be passing in the `$var` -- You really should consider `escapeshellarg($var)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark:** For passing the content of a PHP variable to the shell you **ABSOLUTELY** need to escape it:

```php
$var='fcn1'

$output = shell_exec('./testbash.sh'.' '.escapeshellarg($var));
```

Then you can safely use it as an argument:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World!! $1 has executed.."
```

Comment: Thanks! if fcn1(as an variable content) has received(from php to bash script) I need to run/echo "Hello " and if fcn2 has received i need to run/echo "Hello Hello". How do to this?

Comment: This answer is nothing more than exactly what I answered barring the `escapeshellarg` which should have been a comment as to expand the previous answer and not gum up the thread with multiple like answers .,..

Comment: @Zak I'm sure that a lot of people will agree that the most important thing to know is that you must use `escapeshellarg`, it cannot be _"just a comment"_. In the first place I didn't even show how to use an argument in bash, but OP asked about it.